# How can I be part of the Stack Exchange team?

Tags: discussion, jobs

While I am learning more and more about SE site, it is more interesting, exciting and admiring. I am fall in love with this site slowly. So my specific question regarding this is, How can I be part of SE team if I am interested to work with your team and for your organization?

I am a web developer and I would like to be part of your web development team. How can I apply?

Answer (score 14):

*Disclaimer: I am a Stack Exchange employee :)*

[Here](https://stackexchange.com/about/hiring) is a list of our currently available job opportunities, including [developer positions for the Stack Exchange engine](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/23229/stack-exchange-developer-telecommute-stack-exchange) and [developer positions for Stack Overflow Careers 2.0](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/16279/stack-overflow-careers-developer-new-york-stack-exchange).

Developers for the Stack Exchange core engine are frequently hired directly out of the Stack Overflow community, so the best way to increase your chances is to post good answers and smart questions on Stack Overflow. Building up your rep on Stack Overflow, Programmers, and other relevant SE sites is the best way to make your application stand out.

Comment: Do you guys offer high school internships or telecommute programs? I'd really be interested in that.

Comment: @Dynamic Developers on the core Q&A team can telecommute (and most do). We don't currently have an internship program, but I'd certainly also be interested in seeing one develop in the future.

Comment: How much rep does a user has to have before applying for a job at SE?

Answer (score 11):

Stack Exchange is definitely hiring.  Check out the [careers page](https://stackexchange.com/about/hiring) to apply for any open positions.

Comment: Maybe I should ask you first instead of Abby, but do you guys offer high school internships or telecommute programs? I'd really be interested in that.

Comment: Disclosure: Joe is our [brand new (ish) recruiter](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/12/meet-the-new-additions-to-the-stack-exchange-clan/), so he's eminently qualified to speak on matters of hiring.

Comment: Why don't you guys just pick up your mod diamonds so we can see at a glance that you're of some level of authority :P

Comment: @BoltClock don't get me *started* on that... :)

Comment: @Dynamic ... no high school internships right now, but we'll hopefully launch college internships in the near future.  for most positions (including developer positions), we do allow telecommuting.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn, actually, I think it's cool that they don't show diamonds. If I were doing the hiring, I'd be asking the other SE employees what they thought about user X and if that person demonstrates any behavior that might be suspect... Some people may behave well when there's a diamond lurking but then misbehave when he/she thinks no one is watching. ;)

Answer (score 4):

*Disclaimer: I am NOT a Stack Exchange employee.*

At the bottom of the page, there is a "jobs" link. Clicking that takes you to a ["We're Hiring"](https://stackexchange.com/about/hiring) page and a list of available job opportunities.

List of opportunities as of this writing:

- Stack Overflow Careers Developer
- Stack Exchange Developer
- Product Designer
- Account Executive – Careers 2.0
- Sales Representative – Inside Sales – Careers 2.0
- Office Manager (London)

Answer (score 1):

[Stack Exchange is (was?) hiring](https://stackexchange.com/about/hiring)

[Here are all of the Stack Exchange job listings](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/employer/Stack%20Exchange)

Comment: Care to explain the downvote?

Comment: I was _not_ the downvoter, but it might be because the answer is purely links.

Comment: @Dynamic it is better than ur answer which could be obsolete as soon as tomorrow :-P

Comment: Don't hate bro :-)

Comment: @Dynamic hence the ":-P"

Comment: I know I'm just messin' :)